# Contingent Claim Bounds

Tags: derivatives, finance-mathematics, mathematics

In my course on discrete-time finance we derived the following equality for a lower bound for the value of a not necessarily replicable contingent claim $D$. Here we are looking at a single period market with risk-free interest rate $r$ and $E$ is the expectation operator.
$$\sup\{E[Y(1)/(1+r)]:Y \text{ replicable, }\text Y\le D\}
\\ = \inf\{E_{Q'}[D(1)/(1+r))]:Q' \text{ risk free P-measure}\text \}$$
My question: Which probability measure do we use to compute the first expectation on the left? Is it a risk-neutral one, or is it the real one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming back to this question way later, I managed to resolve my confusion. Using a well-known theorem we have that $E_{Q}[Y(1)]$ is constant on $\mathbb{M}$. Thus, it is irrelevant which measure we are using, since the resulting bound will be the same.